# Cannot access JAX-RS api

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have looked a lot and just cannot seem to get my JAX-RS API to work.

I have a WAR file that I deploy to tomcat (runs in docker) and I am able to access the welcome page but if I try to access the REST API url, I always get a 404 NotFound Response.

Maybe someone could look over my things and tell me if anything is missing or is just wrong (It would be much appreciated):

Example.java

```
@Path("/example")
@Transactional
public class Example {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getExample() {
        return "good";
    }

}
```

ExampleApplication.java

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class ExampleApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> endpoints = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        endpoints.add(Example.class);
        return endpoints;
    }

}
```

Web.xml (in the Jax-RS tutorials is mentioned that no servlet mapping is required if I have an Application class).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>presentation</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
   <filter>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
            <param-value>DEBUG</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

urlrewrite.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN"
        "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">

<urlrewrite>
    <!-- do not redirect references to static resources -->
    <rule>
        <from>/assets/*</from>
        <to last="true">-</to>
    </rule>
    <!-- do not redirect references to REST api -->
    <rule>
        <from>/rest/*</from>
        <to last="true">-</to>
    </rule>
    <!-- redirect everything else -->
    <rule match-type="regex" enabled="true">
        <condition type="request-filename" operator="notfile"/>
        <condition type="request-filename" operator="notdir"/>
        <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">.*(\.html|\.js|\.css|\.ico)$</condition>
        <from>^/(.*)$</from>
        <to last="true">/index.html</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

My Postman requests:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FT2j.jpg

Here you can see that the mapping works, since everything except /rest/* is mapped to the welcome page (I have tried it with /somethingelse/sad/asd).

Comment: which Java you are using, Oracle Java or OpenJDK

Comment: I am using oracle jdk 1.8

Comment: What jars are you including in your project?

Comment: org.tuckey.urlrewriter 4.0.4  -  javax.servlet.servlet-api 2.5   -  provided:javaee-api 8.0 - and some logging stuff

Comment: The javaee jar is only a specification jar. You need a JAX-RS implementation, like Jersey. Add `jersey-container-servlet` and `jersey-hk2`. Both the most recent versions.

Comment: Thanks, i thought every servlet-container has its own default container-servlet implementation where the one for tomcat has jaxrs already included...its so confusing to me. Adding a thorntail profile and executing it makes it deploy to a local jboss (i think) and there it works without that servlet. So i guess i have to provide it for tomcat, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `/rest/example/all` instead of `/rest/example`.

Comment: yeah already did that sry. I removed /all in order to test if a nested Path was the issue

Comment: So after you have remode the /all the application still doesn't work?

Comment: yes its still the same issue. For some reason the requests are not delivered to jax-rs. Something seems to miss

Comment: Then maybe you will update your post in order to reconsider the answer.

Comment: Edited it, thanks for the hint. Now the used URL should be fine